# Is std::vector preferred over heap arrays for dynamically sized arrays in classes?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

If you want to have an array as a member variable of a class there are two main options:

A: Allocate the memory on the heap

```
class X
{
    int * arr;
public:
    UnionFind(int numNodes)
    {
        arr = new int[numNodes];
    }
}
```

B: Use a vector

```
class X
{
    vector <int> arr;
public:
    UnionFind(int numNodes)
    {
        arr.resize(numNodes);
    }
}
```

Which of these is the preferred method? I know one drawback of heap allocated arrays is that you need to take care of deleting the memory yourself.

As a small side question, if an object of X is created on the heap is `vector <int> arr` also in the heap within the object? If so, how come `vector <int> arr` does not manually need to be deleted?

Comment: [learn stl](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/)

Comment: The vector allocates memory for its elements from "the heap". Its destructor does the deletion. That's the whole point of using vector. One line replaces dozens of lines of constructor, destructor, copy-constructor, copy-assignment operator, move constructor.

Comment: @RakibulHasan Better to learn the C++ standard library. Almost nobody uses the STL these days.

Comment: With method B, at least you have a class that is not totally broken. So I would naturally prefer that one.

Comment: @juanchopanza What do you mean by method A results in a broken class?

Comment: it leaks memory, for starters (what I said assumes trivial fixes to make both samples compilable.)

Comment: @juanchopanza That can be taken care of using delete in a destructor though

Comment: Which is not in your code sample

Comment: @user2612743: That's not enough. You also have to take care of the copy constructor, the move constructor, and the assignment operators. But even if the destructor was all you had to take care of, using a vector would be one less thing to worry about, so it's clearly better.

Comment: Once you do that, your class will be broken in other ways, and you will have to write code to fix it. That's more code to look after, more scope for error, for possibly no gain.

Comment: Standard Library, you only appreciate it when yu cannot use it...

Comment: We prefer B because once all the work to fix A is done you'll essentially have done nothing more then rewrite B.  We already trust B.  Don't make us look at A.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you have the choice between a dynamically allocated C-style array and a `std::vector<>`, choose the vector.

- It is safe, does all the alloc/realloc/resizing for you
- It makes you code more flexible, readable, and easier to maintain
- It is extremely efficient in most use cases
- It provides explicit iterators, and plenty of member functions, including `size()`
- Many implementations will do index checking in debug mode to catch out-of-bounds errors

Note that `std::array` exists for most of the cases where a C-array would be preferable (e.g., when allocation on the stack is preferred)

Comment: You forgot one more advantage: many implementations will do index checking in debug mode to catch out-of-bounds errors.

Comment: Is there any stl that allows you to set the array length in the constructor, but once constructed does not allow for the length to be changed?

Comment: you should ask another question for this ! but `std::array` allows you to fix its size at compile time. `std::vector` has constructors that explicit the size, but nothing prevents you from adding more elements.

Comment: Except you can't have the size determined at runtime like `array<int, numNodes> arr;. Is there anything that can replace `vector <int> arr` in the code in my opening post?

Comment: After some reading it seems that this is only possible in C++14 with the use of `dynarray`.

Answer (score 2):

You should prefer `vector`:

- the `vector` and `vector`'s elements' destructors are guaranteed to run at the appropriate times
- things like `.push_back` are massively easier and more concise to use correctly than coding your own checks on "capacity" and resizing/copy-constructing/moving in a C++ object-aware fashion
- it's easier to apply algorithms to Standard containers, use the iterators etc.
- it will be easier to move from `vector` to another Standard container (`list`, `stack`, `map`, `unordered_map`, `deque` etc) if evolving application/library needs suggest it
- `vector` has some housekeeping information that's useful: `size()`, `capacity()`
- before C++11 there was a single performance issue compared to using `new[]` and `delete[]` - you couldn't do an up-front "sizing" of the `vector` to hold however-many elements without copy-constructing their values from a prototypical element (constructor "2" [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector), and [`resize` here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize)) - that meant the constructor or `resize` had to iterate over every element doing copy construction even if the default constructor was a no-op (e.g. deliberately leaving all members uninitialised)

  - this is very rarely relevant or problematic, and indeed the C++ behaviour was generally safer
- because it's a proper class, you can (whether you *should* is another matter) overload `operator<<`, `operator>>` for conveniently streaming arbitrary `vector`s

> if an object of `X` is created on the heap is `vector <int> arr` also in the heap within the object? If so, how come `vector <int> arr` does not manually need to be deleted?

Yes, the `vector` object itself will be embedded within `X`, so will be on the heap too (similarly, it could be embedded in an automatic/stack variable, a global/namespace/static variable, a thread-specific variable etc.).  That said, the `vector` object contains a pointer which tracks any further memory needed for elements in the `vector`, and that memory is by default dynamically allocated (i.e. on the heap) regardless of where the `vector` object itself is held.

Member variables with destructors (such as any `vector`) have them called automatically by the containing class's destructor.